How to apply a .symbolEffect (ie, the animation such as pulse) to an SF system image to a UIButton in UIKit?
Is it possible to apply a .symbolEffect (ie, the animation such as pulse) to an SF system image to a UIButton in UIKit, ie not a SwiftUI app or insert ?
(Pls note that there are a 100 questions explaining how to animate images in general, I am asking how to apply symbolEffect specifically, is it possible in UIKit apps?? - ie not SwiftUI ?)

PS it's trivial in SwiftUI, eg https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-animate-sf-symbols

In UIKit, support for adding symbol effects only exists for UIImageView and UIBarButtonItem. It's really odd that it's not supported for UIButton.
Here's an extension to UIButton that provides the same API as UIImageView:
extension UIButton {
    private var imageView: UIImageView? {
        for subview in subviews {
            if let iv = subview as? UIImageView {
                return iv
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func addSymbolEffect(_ effect: some IndefiniteSymbolEffect & SymbolEffect, options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true, completion: UISymbolEffectCompletion? = nil) {
        imageView?.addSymbolEffect(effect, options: options, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

    func addSymbolEffect(_ effect: some DiscreteSymbolEffect & IndefiniteSymbolEffect & SymbolEffect, options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true, completion: UISymbolEffectCompletion? = nil) {
        imageView?.addSymbolEffect(effect, options: options, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

    func addSymbolEffect(_ effect: some DiscreteSymbolEffect & SymbolEffect, options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true, completion: UISymbolEffectCompletion? = nil) {
        imageView?.addSymbolEffect(effect, options: options, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

    func removeSymbolEffect(ofType effect: some IndefiniteSymbolEffect & SymbolEffect, options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true, completion: UISymbolEffectCompletion? = nil) {
        imageView?.removeSymbolEffect(ofType: effect, options: options, animated: animated, completion:  completion)
    }

    func removeSymbolEffect(ofType effect: some DiscreteSymbolEffect & IndefiniteSymbolEffect & SymbolEffect, options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true, completion: UISymbolEffectCompletion? = nil) {
        imageView?.removeSymbolEffect(ofType: effect, options: options, animated: animated, completion:  completion)
    }

    func removeSymbolEffect(ofType effect: some DiscreteSymbolEffect & SymbolEffect, options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true, completion: UISymbolEffectCompletion? = nil) {
        imageView?.removeSymbolEffect(ofType: effect, options: options, animated: animated, completion:  completion)
    }

    func removeAllSymbolEffects(options: SymbolEffectOptions = .default, animated: Bool = true) {
        imageView?.removeAllSymbolEffects(options: options, animated: animated)
    }
}

Here's some test code you can put in a Playground (along with the above extension):
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let image = UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill")
var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.bordered()
cfg.image = image
let button = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
button.addSymbolEffect(.pulse)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = button

This will show a button with a pulsing eye symbol.

It's really odd that it's not supported for UIButton. Brilliant information!!!  And who doesn't want a pulsing eyeball !

FYI - for more complicated button setups, it's possible that the code to get the image view could find the wrong image view or not find any image view (if the view hierarchy is more complicated). For any future readers that run into such an issue, it will be a matter of adjusting the imageView property in the extension to properly find the right image view as needed.

Purely an addendum to the amazing technique introduced in the other answer ...
In the famous answer there your final syntax for a button is like
yourButton.addSymbolEffect(... etc

which is great.
Another possibility for the same amazing idea,
extension UIButton {
    var imageView: UIImageView? {
        return subsubviews(ofExactType: UIImageView.self).first
    }
}

, then you can write anything anywhere you want ...
yourButton.imageView.addSymboEffect(...
yourButton.imageView.someImageViewExtensionYouWrote(...
yourButton.imageView.someFutureEffectCallFromApple(...
yourButton.imageView.somethingSomeoneForgotToMapOver(...

You can even do slightly dirty things like
yourButton.imageView.backgroundColor = ...

instead of writing 500 lines of config code.
(Some might prefer to name imageView something like resolvedImageView or concreteImageView or such.)
I now use this minimalist edition of the SuperbIdea™ but either way is great!  Great stuff.


Addendum. Every person/team has their own call for digging through a UIKit control and finding a specific view, here's ours. Use whatever you normally use.
///Subviews and similar utils
extension UIView {
    
    ///Remove all subviews from conventional views.
    func removeAllSubviews() {
        for c in subviews {
            c.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    ///Find (deep) children of type. Return an array of them, possibly empty.
    func subsubviews<T:UIView>(ofType WhatType:T.Type) -> [T] {
        
        var result = self.subviews.compactMap {$0 as? T}
        for sub in self.subviews {
            result.append(contentsOf: sub.subsubviews(ofType:WhatType))
        }
        return result
    }
    
    ///Find (deep) children of exact type. Return an array of them, possibly empty.
    func subsubviews<T:UIView>(ofExactType WhatType:T.Type) -> [T] {
        
        var result = self.subviews.compactMap { type(of: $0) == T.self ? $0 as? T : nil}
        for sub in self.subviews {
            result.append(contentsOf: sub.subsubviews(ofExactType:WhatType))
        }
        return result
    }
    
    ///Find whomsoever is my view controller.
    func findViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
            return nextResponder
        } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
            return nextResponder.findViewController()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


Lots of ideas here. Though one downside to exposing an imageView property on UIButton and calling addSymbolEffect on the image view instead of on the button is if in iOS 18 (or some future iOS update), Apple adds direct support for addSymbolEffect to UIButton, all of your code needs to be refactored. With the approach in my answer, you only need to tweak the extension (or eliminate it depending on the versions of iOS you need to support).

For sure @HangarRash there are sundry pros and cons. I think the overwhelming issues are (a) you clarified the anomaly that it is plain Not supported on UIButton, and (b) I for one just had no idea, I'd never thought about it or looked in to it, that, duh, the image in a UIButton is indeed just a plain old UIImageView you can drill down and find - incredibly handy info in many ways!!!
